# Append object to array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm beginner with Python. I know only C++/C# so...
My problem is `append` to my array some object which is `Card` with 2 parameters, card has color and value

part of code doesn't work

```
class Game: 
    table = []
    ....
    def play(self, *players):
        for singlePlayer in players:
            self.table.append(singlePlayer.throwCard())
```

function `throwCard()` in `Player`

```
def throwCard(self):
    cardToThrow = self.setOfCards[0]
    del self.setOfCards[0]
    return cardToThrow
```

"main"

```
player1 = Player()
player2 = Player()
game = Game()
game.play([player1, player2])
```

Do you have some suggestions?

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'throwCard'

Comment: What is inside `players` list?

Comment: I tink the problem is more with `singlePlayer`. Apparently that is *not* a `Player`, but a list...

Comment: players is an array of?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. `singlePlayer` is a list, not a player. So `players` is an iterable of lists, not an iterable of player objects. You would need to post the rest of the code to pinpoint the issue, but you can probably figure it out from here.

Comment: your Game.play() method does not take any arguments (`def play():`), yet you are passing it a list `game.play([player1, player2])`

Comment: So what Schould I now ? I want get one card from player and add to table

Comment: You should post a full [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I forgott about that. Now is code which doesn't work

Comment: remove the asterisk, you just need `def play(self, players):`. With the asterisk you actually get a tuple of a list of players.

Comment: now I have other problem with deletion, but I try make that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Game:
    # ...
    def play(self, *players):
        # ...
```

this `play` method requires arguments to be flat, not giving a list explicitly. I mean, you should ...

```
# your main
game.play(player1, player2)
```

check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters).

Answer (score 2):

try changing:

```
def play():
```

to:

```
def play(self,players):
```

should do it.